# Are Hadamard matrices local?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Can a Hadamard matrix $H_d$ of arbitrary dimension $d$ possess local structure $U= U_1 \otimes U_2\otimes ...$? Can it be nonlocal? Take the 4D Hadamard matrices, which are all equivalent to the class of Fourier matrix
$$
F_4(\phi)=
\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & ie^{i\phi} & -1 & -ie^{i\phi} \\
        1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
        1 & -ie^{i\phi} & -1 & ie^{i\phi} \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)
$$
by $F_4=DPF_4(\phi)P'D'$ for example. $D, D'$ are diagonal unitary matrices, $P, P'$ are permutation matrices. Can it be decomposed to the tensor product of 2 dimensional matrices, and are they still Hadamard matrices? If so, does such a decomposition hold for all cases, or can it be sometimes nonlocal?

Answer (score 2):

The n-qubit Hadamard transform is local; it's just a Hadamard on each qubit.

The n-qubit quantum Fourier transform (which seems to be what you're actually talking about) isn't local. The QFT has the interesting property that every computational basis state is sent to an unentangled state, which can make it appear to be local at first glance. But put in the right qubit states, and you'll find that the output qubits are partially entangled. That can only be done by non-local operations.

[Here's an example:](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT3%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: qft can entangle]

Pure qubits go on, mixed qubits come out. The system as a whole is still pure, but there's entanglement between the output qubits.

Comment: So to recap: n-qubit Hadamard transform is $H_2 \otimes H_2...$, meaning there exist a local version for $d=2n$ dimensions, which doesn't entangle. You've shown that the Fourier transform for $d=2 \times 3$ is entangling therefore nonlocal. So Hadamard matrix can have local and nonlocal form. But I still don't know: (1)if all QFT are nonlocal for $d>2$ (2)what of general Hadamard matrices.

Comment: Also, in the wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform#Example) we see that QFT takes a 3 qubit state to a product state which isn't entangled?